# Need simple HTML5/Jquery Audio player

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I search a simple audio player (HTML5 or jQuery) wich shows only the play and volume button.
It´s ok if it shows the progressbar too but it should be short. 
This player should play all mp3 files in a directory. I hope u can help me...

Answer (score 3):

Try out the [HTML5 audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp):

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source  src="audio.mp3">
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

Comment: and how i can play all mp3files from a directory

Comment: Using HTML5 audio tag its not possible to play all the audio from a directory.

Comment: do u know a html5 player or jquery player wich can play a random mp3 from directory... sorry for bad english

Comment: [Example 1](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/)
[Example 2](http://jonhall.info/examples/html5_audio_playlist_example.html)